# CouchDB<->PouchDB sync. If I restore server from backup, will PouchDB lose data?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

CouchDB<->PouchDB replication for an off-line browser app.

```
C1 <-- P1
C2 <-- P2
C3 <-- P3
```

Imagine CouchDB server crashes and I restore from week-old backup.

```
C3 <-- P3
!!     P3
C2 ??? P3
```

Will PouchDB state re-sync newer data to CouchDB to be "in sync".

I think the answer is yes.  But I'd like to be sure since I'm relying on this as part of my DB server recovery plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PouchDB will replicate the lost data back to CouchDB.

However, you probably shouldn't rely on your users' databases as your backup plan... Why not have multiple CouchDBs on your server and set them up to do bidirectional replication?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a better option.  How about:  PouchDB <-> My CouchDB <-> Couchappy.com  - That would give me simple on-site OS backups and off-site database backups.  Is there an obvious better way?  Thanks again :-)